# Java Linked List pointer confusion

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

This Code below is from a java LinkedList implementation.The method adds a string element at an index point of the list and is taken from one of my cs books.

The linked list class has 2 global private variables

```
Node first;
Node last;
```

```
public void add(int index, String e) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        String message = String.valueOf(index);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
    }

    // Index is at least 0
    if (index == 0) {
        // New element goes at beginning
        first = new Node(e, first);
        System.out.println("ran");
        if (last == null)
            last = first;
        return;
    }

    // Set a reference pred to point to the node that
    // will be the predecessor of the new node
    Node pred = first;
    for (int k = 1; k <= index - 1; k++) {
        pred = pred.next;
    }

    // Splice in a node containing the new element
    pred.next = new Node(e, pred.next);
    System.out.println(toString());

    // Is there a new last element ?
    if (pred.next.next == null)
        System.out.println("ran");
        last = pred.next;
}
```

**My question**
I don't understand how `Node first, last` get updated in the condition below

Suppose you have a list that looks like `["1","2","3","7","4","5,"6"]`

Then you add the the element "4" to index 3

So, the list looks likes `["1","2","3","4","7","4","5,"6"]`, but looking at the code of the **add method** I don't know how the **first** or **last** node pointers gets updated. Because in my mind these are the only pieces of code that run because the index isn't 0 and the last doesn't change

**EDIT**

**The Object Node `first` is used in the toString method(not shown) to traverse through the collection**

```
    // Set a reference pred to point to the node that
    // will be the predecessor of the new node
    Node pred = first;
    for (int k = 1; k <= index - 1; k++) {
        pred = pred.next;
    }
    // Splice in a node containing the new element
    pred.next = new Node(e, pred.next);
    System.out.println(toString());
```

Comment: just to be clear I've tested this add method and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Before the add, the first element is "1" and the last element is "6".
After the add, the first element is "1" and the last element is "6".
You're right that the **first** and **last** dont change-- they don't need to, because you haven't changed the first or the last element.

Comment: well, I tested this,  I filled the list with 10 elements then I added a value to index 6 and ran the toString method which uses the Node **first** to traverse the collection. And the output was correct but I'm not sure how that first node object got updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting bogged down by the way this linked list implementation works.  The `first` and `last` pointers exist to just keep track of the start and end of the list.  Hence, when you insert an element in the middle of the list, these pointers do not get updated, nor is there any need for such an update.  But they *do* get updated should an insert land before the current head or after the current tail of the list.  Here is the code which handles head inserts:

```
if (index == 0) {
    // New element goes at beginning
    first = new Node(e, first);
    System.out.println("ran");
    if (last == null)
        last = first;
    return;
}
```

The critical line here is actually this:

```
first = new Node(e, first);
```

The `first` pointer gets assigned to a new node, which in turn points to the *old* `first` node.  Similarly, should an insert of a new node land at the end of the list, the following code will handle that:

```
if (pred.next.next == null) {
    System.out.println("ran");
    last = pred.next;
}
```

Here the `last` pointer is assigned to the new node which was inserted *after* the old `last`.

But other than these two edge cases, there is no need to update `first` and `last` with inserts.

Comment: the **first** node I believe as references to all other nodes in the list and can be used to generate a toString method which in the other parts of the source code it does, but the line does not have **first = new Node(e,first);**

Comment: `I don't know how the first or last node pointers gets updated` ... I have answered this question to my knowledge.  If you also want a discussion of why you'd want to maintain a `first` and `last` pointer, then maybe that could be a second question at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

If the index is 0, the node is added in the beginnng and the for loop doesn’t work.
If it is 1, the loop again doesn’t execute and node is simply added to the list.
However if it something else, then until the index-1 position is reached the loop shifts each element one step behind. Then the code just outside the loop (which slices in a node containing new element) inserts the element at index.
If after the loop has executed, the index turns out to be the last one then the last node is updated.

Hope this helps!